# Universal Links iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ios-universal-links, itunes-search-api

I am having some trouble in getting Universal links on my app working. Here are the things that i have already done.

-- Created my `apple-app-site-association` file. Here is my file

```
{

    "applinks": {
                "apps": [],
                "details": [{
                    "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.companyName.app",
                    "paths": ["/view/*", "/class/*"]
                }]
            }
}
```

I have not signed my file and i set my project deployment target to iOS 9.2 (so that i don't have to sign this file).

-- Added the associated domain in my project capabilities

```
applinks:companyName.com
applinks:www.companyName.com
```

-- Associated domains are also enabled in my developer portal

-- Updated the provisioning profiles and used the new ones

-- Added the entitlement to the build.

-- Overrided this delegate method

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler`

The file is available from my HTTPS server and i checked the universal links status from this apple validator. https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ The validator is validating this. But when i click on the link which is in iMessage and the link is like companyName.com/view/7375, then it will open in safari and my app does not get any call back.

Any idea what i am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the OS now considers handling your URL in "override" mode -- why it goes into Safari.

When your app resolves a Universal Link, in the upper-right corner of the screen you'll see someting like "companyName.com -->". If you tap that, that's the OS's way of "overriding" how the Universal Link is handled, and opens it in Safari at that time and forevermore.

Try going back into the Messages app and *long press* on your link. After a second or two, you should see an action sheet come up that gives you options like "Open in Safari" and "Open in 'Your App Name'". Select the "open in your name" option. That should then "reset" how the OS views handling your Universal Links, now directing them back into your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks that worked on iPhone but i am using notes application to open the link on iPad pro when i long press the link it does not gives me the option of Open in App. Any ideas why

Comment: First, glad it worked. Second, as for Notes, I don't know. I get the impression that the "long-press -> action sheet -> options for opening" is dependent upon the app and whatever its developers added for support. :-(  This is something I wish Apple did a better job at documenting: the issue, how to work around it, how to "undo" it, how we devs might be able to undo it (and provide that support, even if just as an FAQ, to our users, etc.). :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you support universal links, iOS 9 users can tap a link to your website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your website opens your website in Safari.

Here, how to setup your own server, and handle the corresponding links in your app.

Go Apple developer page

**Register your app at developer.apple.com.
Enable ‘Associated Domains’ on your app identifier.**

**Enable ‘Associated Domain’ on in your Xcode project**
[image]
The error “Add the associated Domains feature to your App ID” will go away once you enable the Associated Domains in your APP ID in developer.apple.com as in the previous step. If it doesn’t go away, quit and relaunch the xcode few times and it will work.

Add the proper domain entitlement and make sure the entitlements file is included at build: Xcode will do it automatically by itself.

[image]

Then create apple-app-site-association file using Terminal

Use this commands for creating AASA(apple-app-site-association) File.

1. cd desktop
2. touch apple-app-site-association

Then open AASP FILE and write this json format data

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [ ],
    "details": [

        {
            "appID": "TeamID.BundleID2",
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Once you are ready with your AASA file, you can now host [https://<>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association](https://%3C%3Cyourdomain%3E%3E/apple-app-site-association)
Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory.

APPLE APP SITE ASSOCIATION (AASA) VALIDATOR
Goto the following link and enter your domain name. It will check if AASA file is valid and is accessible .
Link: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

Once done then add this below code in your Appdelgate

**Swift4**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("Continue User Activity called: ")
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
        print(url.absoluteString)
        //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
    }
    return true
}
```

**Objective-c**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler{
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
        NSURL *url = userActivity.webpageURL;

        }

    return YES;
}
```

Then check your entitlement  add to the app target and run it will redirect to your app.Make sure the AASA File will validate like below screen then its redirect to your application.If anything miss it was not redirect to your app.

**Inside your server any content type validation error came then you can  create one .htaccess file and inside that u can write this code .**

```
<Files "apple-app-site-association">
ForceType 'application/json'
</Files>
```

This procedure worked from my side .I hope your side also working properly. If you enjoyed reading this post .

Answer (score 0):

You also have to implement the following AppDelegate function.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(NSString *)userActivityType
```

I had the same issue. Unfortunately this is not well documented by Apple.