# Firebase Universal links disabled and not working (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to get Firebase Dynamic links that I have integrated on my ios app to open. Following the youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0) I have downloaded my app onto my phone from Xcode. When I try to open up the link I automatically get redirected into safari browser and I'm presented with this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRQAC.jpg

The tutorial runs threw several things that could be the reason for my link not opening up my app

1. Make sure to have the correct URL in the Associated Domain Setting which I do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN1zR.jpg
2. Check and make sure that you have the correct App ID prefix entered in the console which is true because Xcode verifies that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzXDD.jpg
3. Universal link for the domain was disabled because I opened it in Safari and I have to now long press on the link and open it in the app. Now heres the problem.

In mail app, imessages app, and notes app all dont have an option to "Open in . 
Mail (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww0Mj.jpg), iMessages (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCslB.jpg), and Notes app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUadu.jpg).

Even referencing these guides I am unable to solve my problem ([Universal Links iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177732/universal-links-ios)) ([Universal Links not working on iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574711/universal-links-not-working-on-ios10/39603748#39603748))

4. Check to make sure the apple-app-association file in created which it is and it shows that #2's image.

I have exhausted all options and googling for answers is now getting me nowhere. I need help on how to get my Universal Link working again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It helps if applinks is not spelled "applink" in the Info.plist associated domains.

Comment: Are you saying the issue was a typo?